# initialization of vector<float> error during uniform initialization

Tags: c++11

When I compile this in Visual Studio 2015 I get an error: error C2398: Element '1': conversion from 'double' to 'float' requires a narrowing conversion

```
vector<float> v {2.46, 2.58, 2.0, 2.25, 3.0 };
```

But this works

```
vector<float> v{ (float)2.46, (float)2.58, (float)2.0, (float)2.25, (float)3.0 };
```

Is there an elegant solution to this code so I don't have to case all my inputs to float?
Maybe tweaking initializer_list ?

Comment: `vector<float> v {2.46f, 2.58f, 2.0f, 2.25f, 3.0f };`

Comment: @igor-tandetnik, your comment should be an Answer, because it is the correct answer.

Comment: 2.46 is type double. use 2.46f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

shamelessly stealing the comment from [igor-tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik):

```
vector<float> v {2.46f, 2.58f, 2.0f, 2.25f, 3.0f };
```

And then complementing it to make it an answer:

The literal `0.42` has the type double. To have a literal of type float you need the `f` suffix: `0.42f`.

You can read more (well... it's not that much) about [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [floating point literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

Comment: it may be worth pointing out that double can be implicitly converted to a float in a lot of places. But initializer lists have stricter rules about lossy (narrowing) conversions.